# new string creates how many objects?

Tags: java, string, string-pool

if I write a below code

Scenario-1 [Initially no value in string constant pool]

```
String s1 = new String("test");
```

then how many object created?

As per my answer :
two object created :: one is in string literal pool and other is in heap because of new
reference : [refer link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22832671/does-new-string-update-the-string-pool-in-java)

why char[] show in [refer link](https://www.quora.com/String-s-new-string-ABC-How-many-objects-are-created-after-the-above-statement)

Scenario-2 [Initially no value in string constant pool]

```
String s1 = "test";
String s2 = new String("test");
```

then how many object created?

As per my answer :
three object created :: one is in string literal pool for s1 and second is in heap because of new for s2 and third is char[] for s2
reference : [refer link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19672427/string-s-new-stringxyz-how-many-objects-has-been-made-after-this-line-of)

my answer is correct?? please give me exact idea for this which one is right??

Comment: hope this answers your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052442/what-is-the-difference-between-text-and-new-stringtext

Comment: You should read [this article](https://www.todaysoftmag.com/article/1706/common-misconception-how-many-objects-does-this-create).

Comment: "Scenario-1 [Initially no value in string constant pool]" but there *is* a value in the constant pool already - the literal `"test"`.

Comment: in scenario 2 there are 3 object created as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19672427/string-s-new-stringxyz-how-many-objects-has-been-made-after-this-line-of      is it right?

Comment: 3 objects including the interned object

Comment: interned object mean which object?? char[] of string class? as per last comment for scenario 1 there created 3 object also?

Comment: It would have been clear by now if you would have looked at the `String.java` class Would prefer you to go through the article as well (one suggested by  @AndyTurner )

Answer (score 0):

```
String s1 = new String("test");
```

JVM creates two objects one on heap and other in constant pool.

```
String s1 = "test";  //Line 1
String s2 = new String("test"); //Line 2
```

Line 1 will create an object in constant pool if not already present.
Line 2 will create only on heap because one is already there in the pool

If you look at the String class you will find that it initializes a final char[] to create an immutable object but those are confined to instantiation:

```
public final class String
    implements java.io.Serializable, Comparable<String>, CharSequence {
    /** The value is used for character storage. */
    private final char value[];

    .
    .
    .

    /**
     * Initializes a newly created {@code String} object so that it represents
     * an empty character sequence.  Note that use of this constructor is
     * unnecessary since Strings are immutable.
     */
    public String() {
        this.value = "".value;
    }

    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: for second scenario :: As per this answer there will be a 3 object created https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19672427/string-s-new-stringxyz-how-many-objects-has-been-made-after-this-line-of

Comment: char[] is something that should not matter to you. When you ask how many objects are gettin created? This simply means that how many string object are getting created at the end of execution of this statement

Comment: @vishalpatel There are three objects in your example.

Comment: with string total 3 object created ??

Comment: @vishalpatel I have updated my answer

Comment: @downvoter reason??